# Newbie Unable to clone repo

Tags: version-control, bitbucket

I've never used a VCS before and I'm attempting to set one up now.

I'm doing some Game Development with Unity3d. At first I googled how to set up VCS for Unity; and I found this: http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/BurkayOzdemir/20130303/187697/Using_Unity3D_with_external_VCS_Mercurial__Bitbucket_step_to_step_guide.php

I followed it until it came time to clone the repository from within the hgTortoise workbench. When I hit the clone button after copying and pasting the URL to my repo from the BitBucket.org website I received an error: "Repository Git clone https:://username@bitbucket.org/username/projectName.git not found code: 255" and I do understand what an HTTP 404 error is.

Anyone who has used the internet knows it means the page could not be found.

I created this repo as private; is that why it could not find my repo?

Then I proceeded to follow the instructions at BitBucket's "BitBucket 101" help page. I installed Git, had already created a BitBucket account and repo, and the instructions which followed.

I stopped at the point where the help page said to enter some command line things in to Git Shell. I'm running Windows 8.1 and searches have shown me that particular program doesn't exist on this PC.

Am I doing this correctly? What am I doing wrong? All I need is to set up a VCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git and Mercurial are 2 different distributed version control packages.  They both use a command line interface.  TortoiseHG (the package referred to in the step-by-step you linked to) is a GUI extension that's only used for Mercurial.  (HG is the chemical symbol for Mercury, get it?!)

Bitbucket is an online repository that can host either Git or Mercurial repositories.

It looks like you created your repository on Bitbucket as a Git repo and not a Mercurial repo.  Just delete the repo on Bitbucket (make sure you have a good copy of your source code) and recreate it as a Mercurial repo.  Then work with TortoiseHG as instructed in the step-by-step.

[image: Partial screenshot of TortoiseHG new repository]

The fact that it's a private repo doesn't matter.  That just means it will only be visible to you (vs. everyone) and will require a password to push and pull changes via https or ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, it seems that the tutorial that you seem to be using is based on using Mercurial instead of Git.

If you're comfortable with diving into the command line, you can download TortoiseHG, which is a Windows shell extension: http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/

However, there's nothing wrong with using SourceTree as well, which is a GUI-based interface for dealing with both Git and Mercurial repositories: https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

FYI, if you downloaded Git for Windows, it should've provided you with a terminal called Git Bash that you can use for Git commands.

Comment: So Git and Mercurial are different? How so? I'm not even entirely sure what they are :P 

I'm assuming I need to get some software to work with Git because hgTortoise is for Mercurial--right? I am using hgTortoise like the Unity tutorial said which I guess is why it isn't working huh?

Comment: I still need help. Every time I try to clone the repo with TortoiseHG I get this message: "% hg clone --verbose https://Username@bitbucket.org/Username/projectname.git "C:\Users\Username\Documents\repos"
HTTP Error: 404 (Not Found)
[command returned code 255 Wed May 13 09:03:27 2015]" (I've replaced my name with the word "Username").

Why does that keep happening? I did find the Git Bash thing that you were talking about but that too gave me a 404 error.